# LightGBM fit throws "ValueError: Circular reference detected" with categorical feature from pd.cut

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, lightgbm, bins

I have been using with great satisfaction lightGBM models, as I have big datasets with tens of features and million of rows, with lots of categorical columns. 
I like a lot the way lightGBM can get a pandas dataframe with  categorical features defined simply with `astype('category')` without any one-hot encoding.
I also have some float columns, which I am attempting to convert into categorical bins to speed up the convergence and force the boundaries of the decision points.
The problem is that attempting to bin the float columns with `pd.cut` causes the fit method to fail and throw a `ValueError: Circular reference detected`

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507269/lightgbm-valueerror-circular-reference-detected) and actually in the traceback there is mention of the Json encoder, but I have no DateTime columns as suggested by the answer there.
I guess the .cut categories may be not supported by lightGBM but I cant'find any information about this in the docs.

To replicate the problem there is no need of big dataset, here is a toy exmaple, where I build a 100 rows, 10 columns dataset. 
5 columns are of int numbers, which I convert to categorical with astype
5 columns are of float numbers.
Keeping the float numbers as float everything is OK, converting one or more of the float columns to categorical with pd.cut causes the fit function to throw the error.

```
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

rows = 100
fcols = 5
ccols = 5
# Let's define some ascii readable names for convenience
fnames = ['Float_'+str(chr(97+n)) for n in range(fcols)]
cnames = ['Cat_'+str(chr(97+n)) for n in range(fcols)]

# The dataset is built by concatenation of the float and the int blocks
dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(rows,fcols),columns=fnames)
dfc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,(rows,ccols)),columns=cnames)
df = pd.concat([dfc,dff],axis=1)
# Target column with random output
df['Target'] = (np.random.rand(rows)>0.5).astype(int)

# Conversion into categorical
df[cnames] = df[cnames].astype('category')
df['Float_a'] = pd.cut(x=df['Float_a'],bins=10)

# Dataset split
X = df.drop('Target',axis=1)
y = df['Target'].astype(int)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

# Model instantiation
lgbmc = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective      = 'binary',
                           boosting_type  = 'gbdt' ,
                            is_unbalance   = True,
                           metric         = ['binary_logloss'])

lgbmc.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Here is the error, which does not appear if there is not np.cat column.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-751795a98846> in <module>
      4                            metric         = ['binary_logloss'])
      5 
----> 6 lgbmc.fit(X_train,y_train)
      7 
      8 prob_pred = lgbmc.predict(X_test)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, init_score, eval_set, eval_names, eval_sample_weight, eval_class_weight, eval_init_score, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, feature_name, categorical_feature, callbacks)
    740                                         verbose=verbose, feature_name=feature_name,
    741                                         categorical_feature=categorical_feature,
--> 742                                         callbacks=callbacks)
    743         return self
    744 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, init_score, group, eval_set, eval_names, eval_sample_weight, eval_class_weight, eval_init_score, eval_group, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, feature_name, categorical_feature, callbacks)
    540                               verbose_eval=verbose, feature_name=feature_name,
    541                               categorical_feature=categorical_feature,
--> 542                               callbacks=callbacks)
    543 
    544         if evals_result:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\engine.py in train(params, train_set, num_boost_round, valid_sets, valid_names, fobj, feval, init_model, feature_name, categorical_feature, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates, keep_training_booster, callbacks)
    238         booster.best_score[dataset_name][eval_name] = score
    239     if not keep_training_booster:
--> 240         booster.model_from_string(booster.model_to_string(), False).free_dataset()
    241     return booster
    242 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in model_to_string(self, num_iteration, start_iteration)
   2064                 ptr_string_buffer))
   2065         ret = string_buffer.value.decode()
-> 2066         ret += _dump_pandas_categorical(self.pandas_categorical)
   2067         return ret
   2068 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in _dump_pandas_categorical(pandas_categorical, file_name)
    299     pandas_str = ('\npandas_categorical:'
    300                   + json.dumps(pandas_categorical, default=json_default_with_numpy)
--> 301                   + '\n')
    302     if file_name is not None:
    303         with open(file_name, 'a') as f:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\json\encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507269/lightgbm-valueerror-circular-reference-detected), your problem is related to the JSON serialization. The serializer 'doesn't like' the labels of the category created by pd.cut (labels similar to '(0.109, 0.208]').

You can override the labels generated using the labels optional parameter of the cut function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

In your example, you could replace the line:

```
df['Float_a'] = pd.cut(x=df['Float_a'],bins=10)
```

with the lines:

```
bins = 10
df['Float_a'] = pd.cut(x=df['Float_a'],bins=bins, labels=[f'bin_{i}' for i in range(bins)])
```

Comment: Yes I was sfiguring this out! Looks like the Json serialization as used by the lgbm methods has a problem with the `dtype='interval[float64]'`. This is strange because  `df.to_json()` works just fine